# Div positioning and css styling changes in IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I am having small application with some javascript functions on divs. Previously started changes in chrome and all goes well with chrome. But when I tested the application in IE, the functions are not excuting and then finally realised div positioning and styling changed in IE, in fact normal style "cursor : pointer" is also not working for the same div( which is working in chrome) in IE, Can anyone please help me to fix this condition.

Here is the code i used:

```
<!-- onclick function works in IE --> 
<div id="div1">
   <image path which display Next Shape and Name/>
   <div id="innerdiv1" style="top: 20px; -webkit-transform-origin: 48px 0px; transform-origin: 48px 0px 0px;"> 
    <span>Nxt</span>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- onclick function works in Chrome --> 
<div id="div2" style="cursor: pointer;" onClick = "someJsFunction();">
   <dummy image/>
   <div id="innerdiv2" style="top: 20px; -webkit-transform-origin: 48px 0px; transform-origin: 48px 0px 0px;"> 
     <span></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you put up the code used ?

Comment: <!onclick function works in IE>
            <div id="div1">
              <image path which display Next Shape and Name/>
              <div id="innerdiv1" style="top: 20px; -webkit-transform-origin: 48px 0px; transform-origin: 48px 0px 0px;">
                <span>Nxt</span></div></div>
<!onclick function works in Chrome>
            <div id="div2" style="cursor: pointer;" onClick = "someJsFunction();">
              <dummy image/>
              <div id="innerdiv2" style="top: 20px; -webkit-transform-origin: 48px 0px; transform-origin: 48px 0px 0px;">
                <span></span></div></div>

Comment: In the above code, I have 2 divs; but onclick functions work on div1 on IE and div2 in chrome. Same For cursor pointer and some how I can not avoid to remove div2 as its not the 1 case; same scene happening in overall page code of almost 3000 lines.

Answer (score 0):

For such scenarios, you need to find the browser and according to browser you have to handle the javascript functions also.
In my case,

```
!!document.documentMode --> used to identify IE browser
!!window.chrome --> used to identify Chrome
```

and according to browser handled the js function also.